# Any good books to read for complete beginners?

Tags: astrophysics

Currently, I am a Ph.D. student(mathematics) but always loved the field of astronomy hence I would like to read something on the "side" in this field along with my work. So is there any good introductory book(s) for me to read?

Thanks, any help/guidance will be greatly appreciated

Edit: I, personally, wouldnt call it 'too broad' as the question is asking for some introductory books but if not then, its fine :)

Comment: Open-ended resource request are often discouraged, so this may get closed, but check out this reference collection on our meta site: https://astronomy.meta.stackexchange.com/q/163/6

Comment: Broad question, croad answer. Kepler-Dover-Books-Astronomy-Caspar